# Creating new route on Phoenix

Tags: api, routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

i have an application in Phoenix and i'm using PostgreSQL as DataBase. In my DataBase i have a table called "Device_Token" where is stored the token created when someone access the mobile app. I need to create a new route in my API that returns this token so i can get it in my React Native code.

I created a new route in my router.ex file like this:

`get  "/device_token", UserController, :device_token`

And than i need to create a function named "device_token" in my usercontroller.ex file that returns the token code. I think is something like the code bellow but i know it's not right. Someone can help me ? If you need more information, please let me know.

```
def device_token(conn, _params) do
    device_token = Repo.get(DeviceToken, id)
    render(conn, "device_token.json", device_token: device_token)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These [phoenix docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#rendering-json) show you how to render json rather than an html page, so you can do something like this:

router.ex:

```
get  "/token/:id", UserController, :token
```

user_controller.ex:

```
  def token(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    token = Repo.get(DeviceToken, id)     
    render(conn, "show.json", token: token)
  end
```

user_view.ex:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.PageView do
  use HelloWeb, :view

  def render("show.json", %{token: token}) do
    %{data: %{device_token: token} }
  end

end
```